# open angularjs modal popup with one click

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need help with angularjs modal popup.
A click doesn't bring up the modal popup, only 2 click does.
I would have wanted a click to `getAssessmentFee()` and popup the modal.
Please help

**Html**:

```
    <a ng-click="payFee() class="btn btn-xs">Pay</a>
```

**Angularjs**:

```
      getAssessmentFee() {

    var localResource = <IApplicationResource>this.Resource;

    this.$scope.waiting++;

    localResource.getAssessmentFees().$promise.then((data) => {
        this.$scope.fees = data;

    }, () => {
            this.$scope.waiting--;

        }
        );

    this.$scope.waiting--;
}


payFee() {

    this.getAssessmentFee();

   var modalInstance = this.$modal.open({

        animation: true,
        templateUrl: '/App/site/Modals/viewassessmentfees.html',
        controller: 'ViewAssessmentFeeCtrl',
        backdrop: "static",
        size: 'lg',
        keyboard: false,
        resolve: {
            resource: () => {
                return {
                    item: this.$scope.fees
                };
            }
        }
    });
    modalInstance.result.then((result) => {
        this.$scope.reloadPage();
    }, () => {

        });
}
```

Comment: if you copy pasted from your code there is a missing " after payFee()

Comment: Please add whole code.Its looking strange,You made things complicated